# Convert usigned integer( uint16_t) to string. Standard itoa base 10 is giving negative values

Tags: c, string, unsigned-integer, itoa, uint16

I need to convert uint16_t value to a string. I want the string to be a decimal respresentation of the number.

Example: uint16_t i=256 string: 256

I tried with `itoa(i,string, 10)` but when `i` value increases starts printing negative values.
I send the string via the Serial Port.(UART)
It is there some alternative?

Comment: What do you mean while saying: *but when i value increases*?

Comment: It is for firmware so sprintf () I guess it is not a posible choice in this case...

Comment: I have a uint16_t counters, when starts increasing, by the uart is sent 0..1...2, 127, -1.-2..-3... and then when overflows back to 0.

Comment: It sounds like your `itoa` is limited to 8 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sprintf` with `%u` format for `unsigned int`:

```
uint16_t i = 33000;
sprintf(str, "%u", i);
```

Comment: no, the correct format specifier for `uint16_t` is `PRIu16`: `printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", i);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `sprintf()` for common "to string" conversions. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
   uint16_t i = 256;
   char str[80];

   int str_len = sprintf(str, "%d", i);

   return(0);
}
```

For more info look at [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm).

Comment: use `snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d", i);`  even though buffer overflow chance are less.

Comment: @sameerkn, please share link to a library, where you found `snprintf` function with presented prototype

Comment: I'm not sure, but in muy case is for firmware, I want to send the string by the Serial port, snprintf I guess it doesn't work in this case....